# Adding restrictions to API Keys using the gcloud alpha CLI

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam, gcloud-cli

Using [gcloud alpha services](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/services/api-keys) It's now perfectly possible to generate keys programatically:

```
gcloud alpha services api-keys create
```

I can then enable the Maps JavaScript API using

```
gcloud services enable maps-backend.googleapis.com
```

At this point I need to set some HTTP referrer restrictions on that key but the `services api-keys update` command only updates an API key's metadata.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks (haven't tried the API)  as though you can do this at `create` and `update` with `--allowed-referrers`:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/services/api-keys/create

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/services/api-keys/update